# How to move form to center of page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a registration form and am wondering how can I move the whole form to the center of the page? right now its all on the left side of the container, I want it to look a bit something like this: https://id2.s.nfl.com/fans/register?returnTo=http%3A%2F%2Fweeklypickem.fantasy.nfl.com%2F

```css
#Regcontainer {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  top: 0;
}

.Regcontainer h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  color: black;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #212;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: #212121;
}

input[type=password] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #212;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #212121;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#back_form {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Registercontainer">

  <div class="RegForm">
    <h1> </h1>

    <div id="back_glob">

      <div id="back_form">
        <form method="POST">
          <label>FIRST NAME</label>
          <input type="text" name="FName" />
          <label>LAST NAME</label>
          <input type="text" name="SNAME" />
          <br/>
          <label>EMAIL ADDRESS</label> <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
          <BR/>
          <label>CREATE YOUR USERNAME</label> <input name="uname" type="text" /> <br/>
          <label>CREATE PASSWORD</label> <input name="pass" type="password" />


          <br/>
          <input type="submit" name="valid" value="REGISTER" />

        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: This `id="Registercontainer"` does not match this `#Regcontainer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with... but what does it do?

`#Registercontainer` needs to be on the center of the page. Meaning, your fixed with of `1200px` is not going to work too well. I took the approach of reducing the size of your from container to give a better look and feel like this:

```css
#Registercontainer {
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    /* ... your other properties here ... */
}
```

Another note, your `<label>` needs the `for` attribute as specified in **[this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)**.

Let me know if you have any questions, FYI there are many ways to make this work for you.

```css
#Registercontainer {
  max-width: 600px;
  min-width: 320px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 70px auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  top: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

.Regcontainer h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 35px;
  color: black;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #212;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: #212121;
}

input[type=password] {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #212;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  border: 1px solid #212121;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: aliceblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#back_form {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="Registercontainer">
  <div class="RegForm">
    <h1> Register With NackStack</h1>
    <div id="back_glob">
      <div id="back_form">
        <form method="POST">
          <label for="fname">FIRST NAME</label>
          <input type="text" name="FName" id="fname" />
          <br/>
          <label for="sname">LAST NAME</label>
          <input type="text" name="SNAME" id="sname" />
          <br/>
          <label for="email">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
          <br/>
          <label for="uname">CREATE YOUR USERNAME</label>
          <input name="uname" type="text" id="uname" />
          <br/>
          <label for="password">CREATE PASSWORD</label>
          <input name="pass" type="password" id="password"/>
          <br/>
          <input type="submit" name="valid" value="REGISTER" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your form within a `<div>` like this:

```html
<div align="center">
    <!-- insert code here -->
</div>
```

Then in the CSS, add

```css
form {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin:auto` and a fixed width to the parent `<div>`. Example:

```
<div id="Registercontainer" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:250px">
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mwatz122/g9ay26x3/

Answer (score 2):

```css
#Registercontainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Please try this. It might help.